Unable to ssh to ubiquiti cloud gateway ultra
I have ssh enabled in the cloug gateways settings and set an ssh password. I'm using putty.
It will not accept my credentials. I had tried root and the ssh pw. I have tried admin and that password. I have tried root and the admin pw, and admin and the ssh pw. I don't know what else it could possibly be. I'm trying to ssh into it so I can run the adoption command.

What is the precise message you are receiving? Are the credentials configured to allow SSH? Are you able to access the Cloud Gateway's admin web ui or communicate with it via the app?

Generic access denied in putty. Good question on allowing ssh for admin. I am able to access the web ui. I'll check on the allow ssh for admin and will report back.
